# qt: remove item from QListView

Tags: qt, qt4, qlistview

How do I remove an item from a [`QListView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html)? For `QComboBox` it's [`removeItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#removeItem) but I can't find an equivalent function for `QListView`.

Using pyqt4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In QListWidget you can remove directly with `takeAt()`, but not in QListView (read Qt Model/View). You should use the widget unless you need your own model. If QListView *is* what you want then get model, and remove, i.e. `qListView.model().removeRow(row)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use model, not view.

see [https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#removeRow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#removeRow)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a model `model = QStandardItemModel()`. Then, this model should be assigned to QListView `listView.setModel(model)`.  So, you could directly work in the model `model.removeRow(row)` for removing, `standardItem = model.item(row)` for getting the value, `model.insertRow(0, standardItem)` for inserting into the first position. You can also see additional functions to work with models in [QStandardItemModel Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html)